# PostgreSQL: how do I find all possible object types for pg_event_trigger_dropped_objects

Tags: sql, postgresql

Can someone tell me where or how to find all possible **object types** for the  pg_event_trigger_dropped_objects
Official [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/functions-event-triggers.html) about this function doesn't have a list of objects,
I know there is

```
object_type = 'table'
```

But what is the rest of the object types?

Comment: from the manual [37.20. data_type_privileges](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/infoschema-data-type-privileges.html) : object_type character_data = The type of the described object: one of **TABLE** (the data type descriptor pertains to a column of that table), **DOMAIN** (the data type descriptors pertains to that domain), **ROUTINE** (the data type descriptor pertains to a parameter or the return data type of that function). To be confirmed that this answers to your question.

Comment: @EdouardH. thank you :)

Comment: @EdouardH. i think DOMAIN and ROUTINE are not those object types used for pg_event_trigger_dropped_objects

Answer (score 2):

Look at the source in [`src/backend/catalog/objectaddress.c`](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blob;f=src/backend/catalog/objectaddress.c;h=2bae3fbb17486f44379ccfbe6d4ce383660483fd;hb=HEAD#l622):

```c
/*
 * This struct maps the string object types as returned by
 * getObjectTypeDescription into ObjectType enum values.  Note that some enum
 * values can be obtained by different names, and that some string object types
 * do not have corresponding values in the output enum.  The user of this map
 * must be careful to test for invalid values being returned.
 *
 * To ease maintenance, this follows the order of getObjectTypeDescription.
 */
static const struct object_type_map
{
    const char *tm_name;
    ObjectType  tm_type;
}

            ObjectTypeMap[] =
{
    /* OCLASS_CLASS, all kinds of relations */
    {
        "table", OBJECT_TABLE
    },
    {
        "index", OBJECT_INDEX
    },
    {
        "sequence", OBJECT_SEQUENCE
    },
    {
        "toast table", -1
    },                          /* unmapped */
    {
        "view", OBJECT_VIEW
    },
    [...]
};
```